# When I call a method from one class that was implemented in another, it only calls some of the method

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

So, I have two classes, class A and class B.  From class A, when a button is pressed, I have an instance of class B initialize and call its method, `testMethod`.  It sets the text of a a `UITextField` named `text` and calls `NSLog` within this method, but it only calls `NSLog` when it calls the method! I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, here is my code (Assuming both classes are `UIViewController` subclasses, and an instance called `b` was defined in the header file:

**ClassA.m**

```
-(IBAction)sendData:(id)sender
{
    b = [[ClassB alloc] init];


    [b testMethod];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:b animated:YES];
}
```

**ClassB.m** (Yes, the `UITextField` was propertized and synthesized)

```
-(void) testMethod
{
    [text setText:@"Text"];

    NSLog(@"This is the only thing getting called in this method");
}
```

**EDIT: I fixed the problem.  What I did was pass a variable to class B from class A and have it set its text field from there.**

Comment: I assure you that if the NSLog is executed then the other line of code was executed, too. In the event that text is nil, then the message setText is sent to nil which does not raise any error. Set a breakpoint and ensure that text is properly set. You could even use NSLog(@"The UITextField: %@",text]; just to determine wether it is set to nil or properly assigned to a UITextField object.

Comment: I know, but I don't understand this.  The NSLog returns null.

Comment: In that case your access mehtod is fine but text is not set properly. How did you intend to create it? Do you use Interface Builder or do you create it programatically?

Comment: Does the outlet 'text' really refer to the UITextField object within UB? Are they connected properly? Is is an IBOutlet at all?

Comment: Yes, I know that I hooked up everything right.

Comment: Well then provide more code around the text property. At some point you must somehow set it to nil or it was not hooked up correctly. Do you have a screeshot of the IB-Settings?

Comment: BTW, is this your true code? Do you really create the controller classB 'on the fly' with alloc,init and nothing more? Don't you use initWithNibName? Without initializing a view controller with its nib name, everything that you defined in IB does not come into effect. However, I suggest that you share some of your real code with us. Aparently your basic understanding regarding the scope of properties and methods seems to be ok. Then there is no need for any mock-up pseudo code. Let's have a look at the real thing.

Comment: What specifically would you like to see?

Comment: Well, your text property points to nil. We, meaning you, should try to find out why that is the case. If your code sample is real, then I would be interested in how text is initialized within init. If it is not then the value nil is no surprise at all.

Comment: Well, shouldn't that code suffice? I don't see the need for putting anything else in.

Comment: All right. You have got your ClassB. That has a property named text of some subclass of id. Acutally it is UITextField, I guess, but that does not matter. Then you create it using [[ClassB alloc] init]. By then the property's value is nil. Then you do not change anything regarding the value of text. Therefore it remains nil. Then you send "setText" to nil. And nothing happens. That is exactly what your code is telling.

Comment: But I'm not sending `setText` to nil.

Comment: Of course you are. You are sending it to text. And the value of text is nil. Sending a message (meaning calling a method) ot a nil object does not cause a runtime error. In Objective-C it just looks as if the the code is executed. But none of your code is actually called. [text setText:@"some test“] does not do anything at all when text=nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information that you provided: You are using IB and you believe hat within Interface Builder everything is hooked up properly.

And assuming that the nib file of your ClassB view controller is "ClassB.xib".

Instead of

```
b = [[ClassB alloc] init];
```

use

```
b = [[ClassB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassB.xib" boundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did Class b knows the `UITextField` for setting the text?

If not you could try adding the object to the functions header like.

## Class b.h

```
-(void)testMethod:(UITextField *)text;
```

## Class b.m

```
-(void) testMethod:(UITextField *)text
{
    [text setText:@"Text"];

    NSLog(@"This is the only thing getting called in this method");
}
```

## Class a.m

```
 [b testMethod:textfield]; //textfield is a object of UITextField
```

Comment: Great idea, but it still didn't work.  What's even weirder is that everything in the method was called with `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: Well yes, if text=nil, what change could this make? Besides I do not believe that accessing some other controler's view properties is really good business practice.

Comment: Ok. Is classA the `UIViewController` for the view and has set the `IBOutlet` for the `UITextField` in the classA.h? If yes, could you give us your modified method for the `IBAction` and the name of the `UITextField`-variable?